# Mustache without classes

Tags: ruby, mustache

I've started writing a tiny Sinatra application and decided to use Mustache. The [demo](http://mustache.github.com/#demo) looked perfect: Call a function, passing a template and arbitrary variables - done.

However, the [Ruby equivalent](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache-sinatra-example) appears significantly more complex, as you have to pre-define a whole bunch of classes ([one per view](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache-sinatra-example/tree/master/views)).

While I can see that this class-based approach can be useful, I couldn't find a way that's as simple as `render(template, hash)` - what am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/beatrichartz/sinatra-mustache, maybe it will help?

Comment: Thanks, that at least confirms my understanding of the "official" way was correct. I'll look into this.

Comment: While it's not as simple, the "one class per view" approach is actually the "official" way to do Mustache views. You *can* do it with a hash and a string in most implementations (or inline templates, as in sinatra-mustache) but a lot of the benefits of Mustache come from having a proper View or View Model class.

Comment: Some implementations allow for a hybrid approach. For example: https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/runtime_patterns.md

Comment: Most (all?) implementations allow a hybrid approach. That's part of what gives people the impression that a hash full of values is the "right" way to do Mustache :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 m=Mustache.new
            m.template_file = File.join(Rails.root, "app", "views", "orders", "sms.mustache")
            m[:order]=order
            rendered_template = m.render
```

Where order is the object you want your template to use